# How to facilitate full text search from multiple sources on one form? (RoR, WP & ZenDesk)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, wordpress, search, full-text-search

We have a web app that is mainly built atop Ruby on Rails, however we have most dynamic content pulling in a WordPress blog and then a Knowledge Base / Support offering from ZenDesk.

What is the optimal way of offering a search from multiple data sources that don't share a common backend or api from one search box in the core web app?

Comment: After looking more closely at Bing's results, it really seems that they may be an excellent offering. It seems pretty slick with json output and no real limitations when compared to Google's Site Search.  There was a promise to publish the library at this article after some refactoring last summer, however I've not seen anything significant yet: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2009/06/29/learnhub-powered-by-rails-searches-with-bing.aspx

Comment: Found this, going to take a look at it, but was hopeful for some input as to whether this may be the right approach or if I should simply roll my own (particularly due to its age): https://github.com/kfaustino/binged

Answer (score 0):

I would use Solr with the Sunspot gem.

Create a "transient" model for your search result documents in the Rails app. Make sure to mark all attributes you want to display in the search results as "stored" in solr. Then you can have an indexing process from each distinct source which inserts solr search documents of the same type into the same search index. It could even be the same indexing process, just that it can tap all the distinct sources.